# Infection/infections/or

Tags: word-choice

Can I use both "infection" and "infections" and "and" in the second sentence, or should I use "or" instead? I think using "a sight" is wrong.

"I am afraid of insects. They carry infection/infections. I don't like the sight of them and/or their sounds."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am afraid of insects. They carry infection.

This refers to infection in a general sense.

> I am afraid of insects. They carry infections.

This refers to multiple specific infections.

Either form is acceptable. I would tend to prefer the 2nd form, the form using the plural.

> I don't like the sight of them or their sounds.

The speaker dislikes either the sight or the sounds or both together.

> I don't like the sight of them and their sounds.

This suggests that it is the combination of sight and sounds that the speaker dislikes, but it could be used for the same cases as the form with "or".  I would tend to prefer the form with "or" unless I wanted to make the point that it was only the combination that was disliked. But all the options mentioned in the question are grammatically valid.